# Switching dependencies in Gradle depending on platform

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to get Gradle to select different dependencies in my multiproject build based on whether I am building for desktop or for Android.  I have a common subproject (a library) I am trying to reuse.  However, I cannot get Gradle to correctly switch dependency configurations.

My main `settings.gradle` simply includes all the dependencies:

```
// /settings.gradle
rootProject.name = 'myProject'

include 'androidUI'
include 'reusableLibrary'
include 'desktopUI'
```

Now both `androidUI` and `desktopUI` specify `reusableLibrary` as a dependency:

```
// /androidUI/build.gradle and /desktopUI/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':reusableLibrary', configuration: 'desktop')
}
```

`reusableLibrary` itself specifies two configurations, because its dependencies are different whether it's building on desktop or Android:

```
// /reusableLibrary/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'
configurations {
    desktop {
        extendsFrom compile
    }
    android {
        extendsFrom compile
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Just examples, the real list is longer.
    // The point is that h2database is only included on desktop,
    // and ormlite is only included on Android.
    android 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-jdbc:5.0'
    desktop 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.192'
}
```

This *looks* fine to me.  But when I compile either `desktopUI` or `androidUI`, I can see that although the *dependencies* of `reusableLibrary` are being included on the classpath in the manner I desire, the actual JAR *provided by `reusableLibrary` itself* is **not** included.  This of course causes the build to fail.  I suspect I'm not setting up `reusableLibrary` correctly; I'm not clear on what the `configurations {}` blocks do.

Why aren't the compiled items in `reusableLibrary` being included on the classpaths of the UI projects?  And what is the canonical way to include platform-specific dependencies in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original configuration is pretty close to right.  The key is to understand this dependency graph from the [Gradle Java plugin's documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management):

[image: Java dependency configurations]

This is a visualization of the Java plugin's various *dependency configurations*, which is Gradle-ese for "list of dependencies."  When you add `compile` lines to a `dependencies {...}` block, you're adding `Dependency` elements to the `compile` dependency list.

The `default` dependency configuration is special; it is the one included by a `compile project("path")` line unless a different one is chosen with the `configuration:` argument.  This means that when you build the library, the `runtime` dependency list (which *includes the compiled jar from the library itself*) is added to the classpath of the client project.

The original configuration creates two new nodes, `desktop` and `android` in this graph, and couples them both to `compile` by using `extendsFrom`.  They are not otherwise connected to the graph!  Now the problem with the original configuration is apparent: by switching the upstream project to either of these, it is *missing* the compiled code from `runtime`.  This explains the classpath omission.

The solution is a bit more subtle than just aiming `desktop` and `android` at `runtime`.  In order to ensure that everything is correctly decoupled when we add tests, we need one extra layer of dependency configurations to keep `testCompile` from indirectly depending on `runtime`.  Additionally, the library's source code itself may need things on its classpath just to typecheck; we can use `compileOnly` for this.  The end solution looks like this:

```
configurations {
    desktopCompile
    androidCompile

    compileOnly.extendsFrom desktopCompile
    testCompile.extendsFrom desktopCompile // Assuming tests run on the desktop

    desktop {
        extendsFrom desktopCompile
        extendsFrom runtime
    }
    android {
        extendsFrom androidCompile
        extendsFrom runtime
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidCompile "some.android:dependency"
    desktopCompile "other.desktop:dependency"
}
```